# Nameserver Issue?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, http-status-code-404

I have a domain registered with active-domain.com and yesterday I changed my nameservers to my host, but then I decided to switch my host at the last minute and changed them again. Now, 24 hours or so later, the site will still occasionally pull up the site on the old host. It normally resolves itself if I clear cache and flushdns. It's happening for other visitors of my site as well. Any suggestions?

The site is: http://comegetheated.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your TTL is set to 24h:

```
iMac-van-Bart:~ ikbenbart$ dig comegetheated.com

; <<>> DiG 9.6.0-APPLE-P2 <<>> comegetheated.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 40315
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 13

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;comegetheated.com.     IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
comegetheated.com.  86330   IN  A   212.95.48.105

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.            82668   IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            82668   IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.
com.            82668   IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            82668   IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            82668   IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            82668   IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.
com.            82668   IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            82668   IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            82668   IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            82668   IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            82668   IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.
com.            82668   IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.
com.            82668   IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
b.gtld-servers.net. 85051   IN  A   192.33.14.30
b.gtld-servers.net. 18866   IN  AAAA    2001:503:231d::2:30
c.gtld-servers.net. 29970   IN  A   192.26.92.30
d.gtld-servers.net. 29666   IN  A   192.31.80.30
e.gtld-servers.net. 30226   IN  A   192.12.94.30
f.gtld-servers.net. 29971   IN  A   192.35.51.30
g.gtld-servers.net. 2681    IN  A   192.42.93.30
h.gtld-servers.net. 13633   IN  A   192.54.112.30
i.gtld-servers.net. 30226   IN  A   192.43.172.30
j.gtld-servers.net. 29951   IN  A   192.48.79.30
k.gtld-servers.net. 30717   IN  A   192.52.178.30
l.gtld-servers.net. 30225   IN  A   192.41.162.30
m.gtld-servers.net. 29969   IN  A   192.55.83.30

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.220.1#53(192.168.220.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Jun 10 15:22:07 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 495
```

You might want to set it to something lower (4h or so) to prevent this in the future. There is nothing you can do now however. Just wait for the DNS resolution to expire.